# Implementation of Spark's parallelize collections

Tags: java, apache-spark, collections

I have a list of strings which I convert into an RDD:-

```
JavaRDD<String> stringRDD = jsc.parallelize(strings,5);
```

As per my understanding, when we do `jsc.textFile(filename,5)`, then each slave node will parse their individual portions (say from S3), and store the RDD on their memory.

What will be the behaviour in case of `parallelize()`? Does the whole list get passed to each slave node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line :

```
JavaRDD<String> stringRDD = jsc.parallelize(strings,5);
```

The second parameter `5` denotes the number of partitions you want to create for `stringRDD`. If you have 5 workers, they will receive one partition each to work with and perform whatever operation you performed in your code.

If your List `strings` has less then 5 elements, then one partition will most likely be empty and the worker to which that partition goes to will be idle.

> then each slave node will parse their individual portions (say from S3), and store the RDD on their memory

Each slave node will parse their partition but won't store the resultant RDD in memory unless stated otherwise by calling `cache` or `persist` on the resultant RDD. The RDD will only be computed in-memory.

Comment: Okay, so the entire list won't be passed around to the slaves ,correct?

Comment: Yes. Each executor will get a partition of data to work with. The data will only be transferred between executors if a function involving shuffle is invoked, like, `groupBy`, `repartition` etc